# SQL turn row into columns

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id | qns   | ans
---+-------+----
1  | qns 1 | a
1  | qns 2 | b
2  | qns 1 | c
2  | qns 2 | d
```

What SQL query can I use to turn the above table into the table below?

```
id | qns 1 | qns 2
---+-------+------
1  | a     | b
2  | c     | d
```

Comment: You're using MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple options to convert data from rows into columns. In SQL, you can use PIVOT to transform data from rows into columns.

```
CREATE table #tablename
(Id int, Value varchar(10), ColumnName varchar(15);


INSERT INTO #tablename
(ID,  Value, ColumnName)

VALUES
(1, 'Lucy', 'FirstName'),
(2, 'James', 'LastName'),
(3, 'ABCDXX', 'Adress'),
(4, 'New York', 'City'),
(5, '8572685', 'PhoneNo');

select FirstName, LastName, Address, City, PhoneNo
from
(
select Value, ColumnName
from #tablename
) d
pivot
(
max(Value)
for ColumnName in (FirstName, LastName, Address, City, PhoneNo)
) piv;
```

Refer the below link for other options of transforming data from rows to columns:

https://www.sqlshack.com/multiple-options-to-transposing-rows-into-columns/

Comment: There's no `pivot` in MySQL

Answer (score -1):

you can googling it using this keyword "pivot a table in mysql"

or you can look at this url 
http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-a-table-in-mysql/

Note: sorry for my english